# Symfony caching question (caching a partial)

Tags: symfony1

I am using Symfony 1.3.2 and I have a page that uses a partial from another module.

I have two modules: 'foo' and 'foobar'. In module 'foo', I have an 'index' action, which uses a partial from the 'foobar' module.

so foo/indexSuccess.php looks something like this:

```
<?php
<div id = 'container'>
   <div id='part1'>Some data here</div>
   <div id='part2'><?php include_partial('foobar/foobar_partial', $partial_params); ?></div>
</div>
?>
```

I want to cache 'part2' of my foo/indexSuccess.php page, because it is very expensive (slow). I want the cache to have a lifetime of about 10 minutes.

In apps/frontend/modules/foo/config/cache.yml

I need to know how to cache 'part2' of the page (i.e. the [very expensive] partial part of the page. can anyone tell me what entries are required in the cache.yml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to cache the partial named 'part2' of the 'foobar' module, you need to add these lines to the file apps/frontend/modules/foobar/config/cache.yml

```
_part2:
  enabled:  on
  lifetime: 600 # 10 minutes
```

When you then call the partial from your index action in foo, a cached version (if available) will be shown:

```
<?php include_partial('foobar/part2') ?>
```

If you want to cache a different version of the partial for each template that calls it, you should edit the cache.yml file like this:

```
_part2:
  enabled:    on
  lifetime:   600 # 10 minutes
  contextual: true
```